# Ожидание окончания парсинга

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Пытаюсь сделать следующее: При открытии приложения появляется прогресс диалог - начинается парсинг сайта  - по завершению парсинга убираем прогресс диалог и выводим на экран результат парсинга.

Для парсинга использую jsoup.
В моем коде, приложение не дожидается окончания парсинга, убирается прогресс диалог - и вылетает из приложения, я подозреваю что это из-за того что парсинг не закончен, и переменная `nav2Reg` , в которую должен сохранится результат, пуста, так как парсинг не окончен.

Код моего приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

AsyncTask asCheckAut;
ProgressDialog asCheckAutPd;
String nav2Reg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new checkAuth().execute();
}


private class checkAuth extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        asCheckAutPd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Ожидайте", "Выполняю соединение с ресурсом...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... blockRega) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Document doc = null;
                try {

                    doc = Jsoup
                  .connect("http://mobayle.ru")
                  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                  .referrer("http://google.com").timeout(1000 * 5)
                  .ignoreContentType(true).get();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Elements blockRega = doc.select("div.nav2");
                for (Element temp : blockRega) {
                 nav2Reg = temp.text();
                }



            }
        }).start();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        asCheckAutPd.dismiss();
        System.out.println(nav2Reg);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Если приложение "вылетает" прикладывайте к вопросу стектрейс при вылете.

Comment: @pavlofff вылетает из-за того что не дожидаясь окончания парсинга, вызывается `protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   asCheckAutPd.dismiss();
   System.out.println(nav2Reg);
  }` - а так как парсин не окончен, переменная `nav2Reg` пуста.

Comment: зачем внутри потока создавать другой поток

Answer (score 1):

Перед парсингом инициализируйте переменную пустой строкой: `nav2Reg = "";`

Пока задача в `AsyncTask` не окончена, метод `onPostExecute()` вызван не будет.
Очевидно, ваш парсинг кончается провалом и это никак не обрабатывается - `nav2Reg` не получает то, что вы ожидаете получить.

Comment: инцилизировал переменную пустой - теперь не вылетает из приложения. но такое впечетление что парсин не закончен или же вообще не начинался - после запуска приложения через несколько секунд вызывается метод `onPostExecute()` . Я тестировал этот код для парсинга вне **AsyncTask** - парсит как нужно.

Comment: переменную `nav2Reg` не нужно задавать как пустая строка

Answer (score 0):

инциализировать переменную `nav2Reg` как `String nav2Reg = "";` не нужно. все дело в том что в методе `doInBackground` мне не нужно было создавать поток. Так как в этом методе поток создается автоматически